# Kivy Bluetooth Arduino

Tags: python, bluetooth, kivy, kivy-language

Hello I am a 9th grader and I'm trying to create an app which live streams Arduino data on to your phone. I am using kivy to create this app but I don't know how to create a Bluetooth interface with the app I have alredy figured out how to create a live plot with kivy I just need to get the data from the arduino via bluetooth to the mobile app. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't do this by using only Kivy. You need to use pyjnius to get access to Java classes from Python.  Or a better solution is plyer have a look at this https://github.com/kivy/plyer

Comment: @FadiAbuRaid Do u have an example code

Comment: There is an example in the repository I sent you https://github.com/kivy/plyer/tree/master/examples/bluetooth

Comment: @FadiAbuRaid I tried on my PC but it was not working, I had my Bluetooth on but it was still not working. Should I try to run the app on my phone? Will this code and library help me receive data from the Arduino. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: Yes it only works on Android phones and Macs according to the details here https://github.com/kivy/plyer